# What exactly does a sk_buff struct store?

Tags: networking, linux-kernel

I am beginning to work with BPF programs for implementing some networking features in kernel and one of the confusions that I have is - what exactly goes into the `sk_buff` struct?

While on the receive path, most online resources mention `sk_buff` to be allocated for each incoming packet.

However, what happens on the outgoing path? Is a socket message first divided into packets by L3 protocol and then allocated on the `sk_buff`? This also contradicts [some](https://addozhang.medium.com/tracing-network-packets-in-kubernetes-1f8928d9951f) online resources that say a `sk_buff` is allocated before the linux kernel stack does any processing.

So what exactly is stored in the `sk_buff` struct on the receive and send path?